# custom delegate method only gets called in one class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Why is my delegate method only called in MainViewController and not in MapViewController?

LocationService.h

```
@protocol LocationServiceDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) currentLocation: (CLLocation*) location;
@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

LocationService.m

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(currentLocation:)])
{
    [delegate currentLocation:newLocation];
}
```

Here the method get called (in MainViewController)

MainViewController.h

```
#import "LocationService.h"
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LocationServiceDelegate>
```

MainViewController.m

```
locationService = [[LocationService alloc] init];
locationService.delegate = self;

- (void) currentLocation: (CLLocation*) location
{
    // some code, this method get called perfectly
}
```

And in my other class, the same procedure wont work

MapViewController.h

```
#import "LocationService.h"
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, LocationServiceDelegate>
```

MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationService =[[LocationService alloc] init];

    locationService.delegate = self;
}


- (void)currentLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
  // this method does not get called
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Add Breakpoint `if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(currentLocation:)])` here and step thru it.

Comment: Has the view for MapViewController actually been loaded?  I mean, did that second `viewDidLoad` method ever get called?

Comment: @ludesign: if i do that i step only in `- (void) currentLocation: (CLLocation*) location` in MainViewController.m

Comment: @AaronGolden
yes `viewDidLoad` get called

Comment: This is very strange. Something else in your code is playing you tricky. Put breakpoint on your LocationService methods (init and others) and see what is going on; or give us more code so we can help you more.

Comment: I suspect that the heart of the issue will be that you have two separate instances of LocationService.  I feel like you should just have one shared instance.  I bet that only the instance of LocationService created by the MainViewController is actually executing the method that should call out to its delegate.

Comment: just as a negative test what happens if you kill these two lines from your MainViewController? `locationService = [[LocationService alloc] init];
    locationService.delegate = self;`

Comment: @AaronGolden 
That was also my first thought but if I uncomment those lines `locationService = [[LocationService alloc] init]; locationService.delegate = self;`nothing changes, my method in MapViewController.m still doesn't get called

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting delegate to nil somewhere as the code looks fine to me? Please use break pointer to see if it step into currentLocation method implementation in MapViewController.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as i mentioned above I'm using break points already

Comment: It is very difficult to see what is going on with such limited information as the code you have posted appeared to be fine.

Comment: can you post how have you defined delegate for LocationService?

Comment: i've edited my code in LocationService.h you can see how i define the delegate as a property

Comment: With the given information, I can't see any problem with the code.